# How to quickly kill and repoen a uvicorn porcess in same port from another process?

Tags: python, port, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, uvicorn

I have a script that runs a uvicorn process in seperate thread (and does other things as well) based on the config file. I wanted it to reload if config file is modified so I make a new script that starts the main script in the seperate process, watches for the file change and if change occurs kill the previous process and starts the new one. But I found that, after I change the config file, everything else works fine excpet the uvicorn. I also found that, if I don't use script runner script and close (with Ctrl+C) and repoen the main script manually, it works just file.
Here's the structure of my program,

**main.py (main scritp):**

```
def run_uvicorn():
    uvicorn.run(...)

def main():
    # Does something
    starts_in_new_thread(run_uvicorn)
    # Does other things
```

**script_runner.py:**

```
from main import main
process = multiprocessing.Process(target = main)
process.start()

def file_modified_handler():
    process.kill()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target =  main)
    process.start()

observe_file_change(handler=file_modified_handler)
```

Manual restart of the script works file.

Answer (score 1):

this scheme should only be used when developing and debugging code. Uvicorn has the `--reload` flag for this. Try to write `uvicorn.run(reload=True)` and not use this Observer.

Comment: Observer is there to observe the filesystem change. This is what I want, how do you suggest I moniter the config file change without that?

Comment: Yes, unicorn can monitor changed files. Read Reloading with watchfiles, https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/

Comment: I'd suggest using the built in `--reload` facilities here, but http://eradman.com/entrproject/ is a nice little tool for (re)running programs in response to files changing